# Can 'property' (in the ontological sense) be modified into an adjective?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I'm trying to describe the general concept of the scale of a property. By this I mean the order of magnitude of a property, like a mass being on the kg scale or the mg scale or whatever. I want to call this concept something like 'a propertal scale' rather than repeating the cumbersome 'scale of a property'. Is there any way to do this, or some closely analogous substitute? Thanks!

Comment: I think we need more context. Not all properties are measurable along a scale. For example, a dog has 'dogness' but are some dogs more 'doggy' than others? How would you measure that?  Do you have a particular set of properties in mind?   Perhaps it would help if you wrote a paragraph using the phrase "scale of a property" so we can see how you intend to employ it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “in the ontological sense”. Are you talking about the type of unit which your numbers represent, like miles per hour, or feet per second per second, or covid infections per million people, or tons per truckload, or degrees Fahrenheit per thousand feet of altitude, or furlongs per fortnight, or bushels per acre, or acre-feet per year? Or are you talking about a bare scalar value that has no inherent unit connected with it like parts per million or parts per billion without saying what the part is?